# Entity-Framework dynamic QueryInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, wcf-data-services

we use entity-framework version 6.0.1 together with wcf data services. Now we build a dynamic DBContext based on this project: http://dynamixdata.codeplex.com/. This project builds dynamic poco classes with typebuilder and uses it. For server side filtering data we need a queryinterceptor. Here is an example implementation we added:

```
[QueryInterceptor("Interventions")]
    public Expression<Func<Intervention, bool>> OnQueryInterventions()
    {
        var inter = ((IObjectContextAdapter)CurrentDataSource).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Intervention>();
        return (i => inter.Any(j => j.Object.StartsWith("changement") && i.Id == j.Id));
    }
```

Our problem is, that we have typed classes only at runtime. So service fails because data services are checking type of object for example Intervention. Not only type there is a check to method signature. We tried to use poco-base or dynamic instead of Interventation, but that will not work, too.

Is there any other method to create Interceptors? With EF? Maybe on config creation when setting dbcontext? Any hack?

(At this moment we use server transfer to rewrite url but this is really ugly)

Thanks